# CMAKE API - producing an AST from the root CMakeFile

Tags: c++, cmake, code-analysis, clang

I'm toying around with the idea of creating some tools for code analysis. My projects of interest all use cmake and clang++ now.

To start with I need to get my hands on the CMake AST for a certain project. In essence I want to do the following (psuedocode):

```
CMakeAst & project_ast = CMakeAstBuild("/path/to/the/root/directory/of/a/project");
```

From the AST I will extract the targets, the (default) compiler switches configured (, the (default) #DEFINE's, the include paths etc. All this information will be required for libClang to build an accurate AST for the targets defined in my project-under-analysis.

So libclang is a clean documented interface to clang. I now need the information for CMake Could someone guide me to getting my own  CMake AST producing main program. Any information is welcome.

A c-main and the relevant compile switches in the form of a MakeFile would make my day :D

**Edit: My Progress (cmake 2.8.5)**

`cmakemain.cxx` contains the main method and sets up the context for the main engine which seems to be a class `cmake` which is contained in `cmake.h`. `cmake.h` has good documentation.

The build tools seem to build monolithic executable tools, no intermediary library is created. bit messy :/.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you with your problem, but maybe with its formulation: Do you want to parse a CMake Makefile or do you want to extract the dependency graph? The latter would be very ill-defined with the term AST because it's neither about syntax nor a tree.

Comment: CMake has it's own build description `language`. Before it can generate the input for another build environment it needs to parse the build description. The intermediate form is most definetely an AST. Perhaps my vocabulary is rough, am I really wrong ?

Comment: No, it's fine, I just couldn't see the use in the AST and thought you wanted the dependency tree.

Comment: @Hassan: Your answer to "do you want a tree" wasn't very clearly YES or NO.  Being pedantic, I have no idea how CMake works; it may not have an intermediate form.   I assume you really do want a tree representing the content of a CMake file.   So... define a grammar for CMake (maybe steal the one they likely use?) and parse it.  What is the actual issue?